# Click event on dynamic element fires after second click only - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to execute a function when clicking on a dynamic element(does not exist on page load), here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('body').off('click','.itemAttribute').on('click','.itemAttribute',function(){
        var title = jQuery(this).find('img').attr('title');
        jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('select').val(title).change();
  });
})
```

However the code is only executed on second click..

HTML's of Dynamic element:

```
<ul class="attribute-list">
<li class="itemAttribute tbn-images" rel="837"><img src="pathxxx.jpg" title="UNIVERSITY BLUE/DARK"></li>
<li class="itemAttribute tbn-images" rel="838"><img src="pathxdfhdxx.jpg" title="UNIVERSITY RED/DARK"></li>

</ul>
```

static HTML:

```
<select name="super_attribute[92]" id="attribute92" class="required-entry super-attribute-select" onchange="MagicToolboxChangeOptionConfigurable(this, 'farve');" style="visibility: hidden; ">

<option value="">Please choose...</option>
<option value="837" price="0">UNIVERSITY BLUE/DARK</option>
<option value="838" price="0">UNIVERSITY RED/DARK</option>
</select>
```

Please help..

NOte: When adding an alert in the code, the alert is executed in first click, seems the problem is:

```
jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('select').val(title).change();
```

:(

Comment: use using live click event and try

Comment: can you share the html as well

Comment: also how did you test it....

Comment: The provided code looks fine.. Could you please setup a jsfiddle?

Comment: I cant reproduce http://jsfiddle.net/e7m3vce8/

Comment: `el.parent().parent().find(...` is very fragile. I'm guessing it's failing on first run due to other changes in the dom. Rewriting this using class or data-attribute selectors might solve your problem.

Comment: the alert works fine in original code too, the problem lies in the change i am trying to make with the SELECT :(

Comment: Are you sure about the select? You have used "title" attribute to set the value of select. But if you look at the code, it should be "rel" attribute of li for getting the value and setting in the select. Anyway, are you sure about this  onchange="MagicToolboxChangeOptionConfigurable(this, 'farve');"  . Maybe when you trigger the change on select, this function is failing

Comment: FYI the MagicToolboxChangeOptionConfigurable(this, 'farve') works on second click too  :(

Answer (score 0):

To select an item based on the value, you should be querying the `rel` attribute of the `<li>` element.

```
var value = this.getAttribute('rel');
jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('select').val(value);
```

Note that the selector you're using is fragile, but in my given example below it works as expected.

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/hoyodeselo/1/)

Comment: @wasiim_dev It works in the given demo, so you will need to add more details to your question, provide a fiddle that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(this).parent().parent().find('select').val(title).change();
```

change to

```
jQuery('#attribute92').val(title);
```